# Nsis MultiLanguage display language 2 times in language selection textbox

Tags: nsis

I have created my windows application installer using NSIS 3.02.1.
In language selection textbox, language is display 2 times.

> **EX.**
>
> English/English
>
> Chinese (Simplified) / Hanyu (Jiantizi)
>
> Russian / Russkij...

In my previous setup, which was build using NSIS 2.46 this language setup is looks like :

> English
>
> Chinese
>
> Russian...

I don't want to change this in my language selection setup. How can I achieve language selection setup as define in NSIS 2.46 in NSIS 3.02.1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you still support Windows 95/98/ME then I would recommend that you use NSIS v2.51, it has all the security updates from NSIS v3 and better language support in the language selection dialog.

If you only support newer versions of Windows then you should add `Unicode True` to your script, this will display the native name of the language in the language selection dialog and all languages are supported on all systems.

If you insist on creating ANSI installers with NSIS v3 then you can use the undocumented `LANGFILE_LANGDLL_FMT` define:

```
OutFile test.exe
RequestExecutionLevel user

!define LANGFILE_LANGDLL_FMT "%NATIVEASCIINAME%" ; %NATIVENAME% can also be used but it will display ? in some cases.

!include "MUI2.nsh"
!insertmacro MUI_RESERVEFILE_LANGDLL
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_COMPONENTS
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_INSTFILES
!insertmacro MUI_LANGUAGE "English"
!insertmacro MUI_LANGUAGE "Swedish"
!insertmacro MUI_LANGUAGE "Russian"
!insertmacro MUI_LANGUAGE "SimpChinese"

Function .onInit
    !insertmacro MUI_LANGDLL_DISPLAY
FunctionEnd

Section
SectionEnd
```